# Flask App Postgres Dependencies

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I've got a web app written in Flask. I'm trying to set my app up so that it'll easily download all of the library dependencies it needs. I followed the [guide here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/distribute/) to structure my application like this:

```
MyApp/
  runserver.py
  setup.py
  MyApp/
    templates/
    static/
    __init__.py
    views.py
    x.py
    y.py
    z.py
```

My setup.py file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
  name='MyApp',
  version='1.0',
  packages=find_packages(),
  include_package_data=True,
  zip_safe=False,
  install_requires=[
    'flask',
    'flask-bootstrap',
    'flask-moment',
    'flask-wtf',
    'flask-script',
    'wtforms',
    'psycopg2']
  )
```

I then run the setup file like so:

```
python setup.py install
```

It starts to do its thing, but then it always chokes on installing psycopg2:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
error: Setup script exited with 1
```

I've searched around, and none of the solutions I've read about have worked. Any advice would be rad!

Comment: You need to install Postgres on the system. That's a dependency outside of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Install the libpq-dev package.